# ncurses WINDOW* disappears after console resize

Tags: c++, ncurses

So, let's say we have a

```cpp
WINDOW *main_win=newwin(50, 80, 1, 0); // 50 rows, 80 columns
WINDOW *status_win=newwin(3, 100, 51, 0); // Status bar
WINDOW *interaction_bar=newwin(1, 200, 0, 0);
```

I have a function that prints strings onto it (`mvwaddstr`) and it works as planned. But after resizing the terminal to particularly <50 columns and resize it back to >53 columns, the `status_win` just magically disappears. `wclear` and `wrefresh` doesn't render anything onto it.

I've tested something like

```cpp
delwin(main_win);
delwin(status_win);
delwin(interaciton_bar);
main_win=newwin(50, 80, 1, 0);
status_win=newwin(3, 100, 51, 0);
interaction_bar=newwin(1, 200, 0, 0);
```

Surprisingly, the status_win gets rendered back. But there's a problem.

I use `int ch = wgetch(main_win);` to get my keyboard input. Somehow it can read keys like 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', but when it comes to keys like KEY_LEFT and KEY_RIGHT, my console just starts to jitter and seems like it isn't being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the disappearing window (likely reduced to 1x1, which is not "magically disappears").  ncurses will attempt to keep a window which has the same width (or height) as *`stdscr`* preserve that relationship when resizing, as mentioned in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resize_term):

> When  resizing  windows,  **`resize_term`**  recursively  adjusts subwindows,
> keeping them within the updated parent window's limits.  If a top-level
> window  happens  to extend to the screen's limits, then on resizing the
> window, **`resize_term`** will keep the window extending to the corresponding
> limit, regardless of whether the screen has shrunk or grown.

Regarding "starts to jitter", if your window did not enable [`keypad`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) (as in the given fragment of code), then the cursor keys will be seen as a sequence of characters rather than as a single code:

> The  **`keypad`**  option  enables the keypad of the user's terminal.  If enabled (*bf* is TRUE), the user can press a function key (such as an arrow
> key)  and  **`wgetch`**(3x)  returns a single value representing the function
> key, as in **`KEY_LEFT`**.  If disabled (*bf* is FALSE), curses does not  treat
> function keys specially and the program has to interpret the escape sequences itself.  If the keypad in the terminal can be turned  on  (made
> to  transmit)  and  off  (made to work locally), turning on this option
> causes the terminal keypad to be turned on when **`wgetch`**(3x)  is  called.
> *The default value for keypad is **FALSE***.